# How to set an array's value from a JSON file?

Tags: ios, json, swiftui

I am building a SwiftUI app for iOS to help me and my classmates keep up with assignments.

The way I am syncing homework across devices is by pushing some JSON with the assignments into GitHub Pages and then the app parses the JSON code into a sleek and simple Section within a Form.

I would like to have the following JSON...

```
[
{
    "subject": "Maths",
    "content": "Page 142, exercises 4, 5, 6.",
    "dueDate": "15/01/2022"
},

{
    "subject": "English",
    "content": "Write an essay about your favorite subject. 2 pages at least.",
    "dueDate": "18/01/2022"
},

{
    "subject": "Chemistry",
    "content": "Learn every element from the Periodic Table.",
    "dueDate": "16/01/2022"
}
]
```

... turn into something that looks like this:
[image: Xcode Previews with the desired result]

The easiest way would be to create about 5 Sections and, if there aren't 5 assignments, leave them empty. This solution didn't work because not having 5 assignments in the JSON file means the function that handles the file would abort because `JSONDecoder` would return `nil` when unwrapping the 4th assignment.

I've been struggling for quite a while to find a solution. I tried this:

```
struct Assignments: Decodable {
let subject: [String]
let content: [String]
let dueDate: [String]
}


struct AssignmentView: View {

@State private var currentNumber = 0
@State private var numberOfAssignments = 0

@State private var subject = [""]
@State private var dueDate = [""]
@State private var content = [""]

func downloadAssignments() {
let assignemtURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/assignments.json")!
    var assignmentRequest = URLRequest(url: assignmentURL)
    assignmentRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    assignmentRequest.attribution = .developer
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(assignmentRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Could not get assignments. :/")
        } else {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let assignmentJSON = "\(data)"
            let jsonData = assignmentJSON.data(using: .utf8)!
            let decodedAssignments: Assignments = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Assignments.self, from: jsonData)
            let numberOfAssignments: Int = decodedAssignments.count
            // Here comes the problem. How do I create an array / modify an existing array with each individual subject taken in order?
    }
  }
}

var body: some View {
    let _ = downloadAssignments()
    VStack {
        Form {
            Section {
                    ForEach(0..<numberOfAssignments) {
                        Text("\(subject[$0]) - Due \(dueDate[$0])")
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
                        Text("\(content[$0])")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**How can I get the value of each variable from the JSON file and combine it into an array (example: `var subjects = ["Maths", "English", "Chemistry"]`)?**

I've been looking for an answer for weeks with no solution. Some help on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: put your JSON into [quicktype](https://quicktype.io), them click on the toggles. It will give you all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things to point out in your code. I'm afraid I can't present you a full solution, but these pointers might help you go into the right direction:

1. The structure of your `Assignments` model doesn't match the JSON (and is also not really easy to work with in the list). Instead of having a single model which has an array for *each property*, there should one model object per assignment

```
struct Assignment: Decodable {
    let subject: String
    let content: String
    let dueDate: String
}
```

and then you can decode/store an array of those:

```
let decodedAssignments: [Assignment] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Assignment].self, from: jsonData)
```

2. Triggering the download as a side-effect of the `body` being evaluated is not a good idea, because this does not happen only once. In fact, whenever you modify any state of the view it would re-trigger the download, basically leaving you in an infinite download-loop. Instead, a better place to start the download would be when the view appears:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // ...
    }
    .onAppear(perform: downloadAssignments)
}
```

3. `NSURLConnection` is an extreeeemly old API that you don't want to use nowadays (it has been officially deprecated for 6 years now!). Have a look at [`URLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) instead.